# is mqtt support both one to many and many to one?

Tags: mqtt

Recently I had read an iot article
http://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2014/february/article2.php
In this he is saying that, by mqtt protocol clients can communicate both in one to many and many to one ways. In the mqtt spec itself mentioning about the one to many but I had little confusion in many to one. What I understood is, many clients are publishing on same topic and there is only one subscriber for these different publishers.Then how the subscriber(user) should identify message belongs to which publisher?
       Another doubt, if two publishers used the same topic to publish their data without knowing each other, because of every client is connected to the internet, the subscriber will get both the datas. But that is not what the subscriber expected.He wants data from only one publisher. Is there any chance to occur the same scenario in mqtt communication?

Answer (score 13):

Here are some facts about MQTT that will perhaps help you understand.

1. A publisher does not "own" a topic. A publisher may choose to
   publish a message to ANY topic (assuming it is a valid MQTT topic).
2. Given point 1 above, any number of publishers may simultaneously
   publish to the same topic.
3. A client can choose to subscribe to
   specific or wildcarded topics to receive  information published from
   any publisher.
4. A client can be both a publisher and subscriber
   (it would even be possible for a client to receive its own published
   message).
5. The MQTT Broker takes care of managing all
   relationships between clients. Clients dot not know (or care) which
   other clients are currently connected to the broker. Publishers and
   subscribers are completely decoupled although they may communicate
   using MQTT capabilities (pub/sub).
6. It is possible that a
   publisher's message is discarded because no subscribers are
   currently interested in that message. (e.g.: publisher publishes to
   topic "topic1". If no subscribers had previously requested a
   subscription to "topic1", the message will be discarded by the MQTT
   broker since it has no client to send it to).
7. A single publisher
   can publish to multiple clients at once. (e.g.: 10 clients come
   online and request a subscription to topic "topic1". Another client
   comes online and publishes to "topic1". All 10 subscribers to
   "topic1" will receive the message. The publisher simply had to publish one message to the MQTT broker, the MQTT broker is responsible for relaying the message to all 10 subscribers).

Hopefully these tidbits of information will help you understand, please let me know if I anything is still unclear.

Comment: "Given point 1 above, any number of publishers may simultaneously publish to the same topic." What does this mean?, so  if two clients  publishes to the same topic, for example: "topic1"(assume both these clients doesn't use the topic hierarchy just only "topic1") .Another client is subscribing to the "topic1", then he will receive both values.But  how can he seperate values of both publisher clients? and also if the subscriber client is only interested in one   publisher client, then how can he block the other publishers value?

Comment: I would suggest reading up on the Publish/Subscribe Pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern.
To answer your question specifically, since you own your topic architecture you could easily design your system to have publishers publish to their own topics. Keep in mind that the pub/sub pattern strives to keep a loose coupling between publishers and subscribers. If your subscriber needs to know which publisher is sending a specific message, you are probably not designing your system properly.

Comment: I might be able to clarify that - consider lighting control messages that define light state, eg the hue bulbs.  You could have the topics /house/hue/<liteno>/state covering the state information of the various buibs, and if if the messages contained the publisher id, then if it was the lighting controller it is a statement about what is, and anything else represents a request for what might be - the light control and the clients all publish and subscribe to the same set of urls and use publisher information to further filter the data

Answer (score 0):

"It is possible that a publisher's message is discarded because no subscribers are currently interested in that message. (e.g.: publisher publishes to topic "topic1". If no subscribers had previously requested a subscription to "topic1", the message will be discarded by the MQTT broker since it has no client to send it to)" 
Is it applicable even by publishing with retain flag set? because I understood that if retain flag is set the broker will store the session of that particular topic and whenever a subscriber is available to that same topic.The broker will handover those messages to the subscribed client.

Comment: That is partly correct. The MQTT broker will retain only the very last message published on a given topic (and is allowed to discard it at any time if the QoS value is at 0). To give you an example of where this is useful, let's take a stock market application. A publisher publishes market data (topic: GOOG, payload: 650.50$) every time new data is available. Having set the retain flag, a subscriber would receive the most recent data available and wouldn't have to wait until the publisher publishes a message to know the price of the GOOG stock.